# How to prove that a subspace is a proper subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces

How to prove that a subspace $X \subset V$ ($V$ is vector space) is a proper subspace?

I've read that:

> A subspace $X$ is called a proper subspace of $V$ if it is neither the whole space $V$ nor the zero subspace $\{0\}$.

But am unsure about how to display this?

Comment: What is the difficult in following the definition? Do you have an example at hand?

Comment: Just use the definition. Display some nonzero vector in it, and some vector not in it.

Comment: @Jack How am I supposed to show that $X$ is not equal to $V$?

Comment: @mavavilj: you can find some $v\in V$ such that $v\not\in X$.

Comment: Is this a question about *notation* or about *method of proof*?

Comment: @kimchilover Method of proof.

Comment: You might also have to show that $X$ is a vector subspace.

Comment: If $V$ is non-zero, the zero subspace *is* a proper subspace, albeit it is trivial

Comment: @Bernard: it is not a proper subspace by the definition in OP.

Comment: Sure, but it is incorrect. A proper subspace is a subset which is a proper subset. Would you say the empty set is not a proper subset of a non-empty set?

Comment: Here is a question for you, where you can test whether you have understood it. Let $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ with basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$. Consider the subspace $X$ generated by $e_1-e_2,e_2-e_3$ and $e_3-e_1$. Is $V=X$ or not?

Comment: Just prove that $X\neq V$ and $X\neq \{0\}$ ???

Answer (score 4):

If we are working with finite dimensional vector spaces (which I assume we are) then there are a few ways to do this. If $X\subseteq V$ is our vector subspace then we can simply determine what $\dim X$ is. If $0<\dim X<\dim V$ then we know that $X$ is a proper subspace. The easiest way to check this is to find a basis for the subspace and check its length.

Another more manual way to do this is to check that there is a nonzero vector in $X$, and also that $V$ contains a vector that is not in $X$.